# AIMMS: is it possible to minimize two variables together?

Tags: constraints, constraint-programming, aimms

For a project of bike sharing simulation, I was asked to implement a constraint programming solver by AIMMS. As some of you know, AIMMS has a mathematical program where you have to specify which variable you want to be maximized or minimized, in respect of all constraints. The problem is that you can specify only ONE variable for this operation. Instead, I need to minimize two variables about

- the routing cost of trucks rebalancing the number of bikes in each station at the end of day
- the good balance of work for each trucks expressed as the average deviation from the medium work

My first program finds a solution with the minimum cost (because I can minimize only the variable of cost) but the work among all trucks is not equal: some work too much, some work very little. So I need to minimize too the difference of work and thst's why I introduced a second variable to be minimied.
Do you know how I can combine together these two variables to get a unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is no magical solution for this kind of situation. This is a typical Multi-Optimization problem. My opinion is that you should built a pareto frontier (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency)